# What's the alternative for TensorFlow VocabularyProcessor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

It says that it is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Another line says "Please use tensorflow/transform or tf.data.". I searched the internet but I couldn't find the answer. Here is the line that gives me the warning:

```
# Change texts into numeric vectors
vocab_processor = tf.contrib.learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor(max_sequence_length,min_frequency=min_word_frequency)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not solved it yet either.
One set of explanation is here:

> `tf.contrib.learn.preprocessing:` Deprecated. The python-only
>   preprocessing functions are not a good fit for TensorFlow. Please use
>   tf.data, and consider tensorflow/transform for more complex use cases.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/contrib/learn/README.md

This example should help... but it doesn't explain much
https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/blob/master/examples/sentiment_example.py

```
review_indices = tft.compute_and_apply_vocabulary(
                    review_tokens, top_k=VOCAB_SIZE)
```